# Why are there several alerts popping up at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, confirm

I'm trying to make this donut clicker game, which is supposed to be similar to cookie clicker. When you select a item from the shop, a confirm is supposed to pop up to confirm that you want to buy the item. I've made the clicking easier in the code below. (you might want to make the code full screen) My question is, why do the confirm pop ups appear multiple times in a row? In my code, there is only *one* confirm when you click the item, so I really don't know what causes it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 tacoClick();
});
function tacoClick() {
 //hide the items
 $(".item").hide();
 
 //defining some store items
  var clickBonus1 = {
  price: 6,
  amount: 25,
 };
 var clickBonus2 = {
  price: 75,
  amount: 10,
 };
 var clickBonus5 = {
  price: 150,
  amount: 5,
 };
 var autoClick = {
  price: 500,
  amount: 1,
 };
 var autoBonus1 = {
  price: 700,
  amount: 10,
 };
 var autoBonus2 = {
  price: 1000,
  amount: 10,
 };
 var autoBonus5 = {
  price: 1200,
  amount: 5,
 };
 var laser = {
  price: 2500,
  amount: 1,
 };
 var battery = {
  price: 1500,
  amount: 666,
 };
 var energyPotion = {
  price: 1500,
  amount: 20,
 };
 var key = {
  price: 500000,
  amount: 1,
 };
 
 //defining the player
 var player = {
  clicks: 0,
  money: 5,
  energy: 100,
  items: ["none"],
  clickAmount: 1,
  energyLost: 0.5,
  waitTime: 600000,
 };

 //clicking! YAY :)
 $("#donut").click(function() {
  //adding num clicks, money, and taking away energy
  player.clicks += player.clickAmount;
  player.energy -= player.energyLost;
  player.money += player.clickAmount / 10;

  //showing player status on the status bar
   document.getElementById("clickNum").innerHTML = player.clicks;
   document.getElementById("playerEnergy").innerHTML = Math.floor(player.energy);
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = Math.floor(player.money);
  
  //tired mode
  if(player.energy < 1 && player.energy > -1) {
   alert("You ran out of energy! You'll have to wait ten more minutes until you can play again!");
   $("body").fadeOut();
   window.setTimeout(function revive() {
    $("body").fadeIn();
    player.energy = 100;
   }, player.waitTime);
  }
  
  //the items! now, it gets really tricky...
   if(player.money > 6) {
    $("#clickBonus1").show();
   $("#clickBonus1").click(function() {
    var confirmBuy = confirm("Do you want to buy this item for $50?");
    if(confirmBuy) {
     if(player.money > 6) {
      player.clickAmount += 1;
      player.money -=2;
      document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = Math.floor(player.money);
     } else {
      alert("You don't have enough money!");
     }
    }   
   });
   }
 });
}
```

```css
* {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#donut {
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
 /*background-color: grey;*/
 border-radius: 500px;
}

#donut:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 505px;
 height: 505px;
 transition: ease 0.3s;
}

body {
 /*border: 1px solid black;*/
 width: 960px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 480px;
 margin-top: 200px;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #EAFFEA;
 transition: ease 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
 <script>
   
 </script>
 <style>
  
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="statusBarWrapper">
  <div id="clickNumWrapper">Total clicks: <span id="clickNum">0</span></div>
 <div id="devicesWrapper">Items: <span id="devices">none</span></div>
 <div id="energyWrapper">Energy: <span id="playerEnergy">100</span></div>
 <div id="moneyWrapper">Money: $<span id="money">5</span></div>
</div>
<div id="tacoWrapper">
 <img id="donut" src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/LTd/jRj/LTdjRjKpc.png"/>
</div>
<div id="shopWrapper">
  <ul id="shop">
  <div class="item" id="clickBonus1">Click bonus (+1 donut / click) <br/> Price: $50</div>
  <div class="item" id="clickBonus2">Click bonus (+2 donut / click) <br/> Price: $75</div>
  <div class="item" id="clickBonus5">Click bonus (+5 donut / click) <br/> Price: $150</div>
  <div class="item" id="autoClick">Auto Click (automatically +1 / second) <br/>  Price: 500</div>
  <div class="item" id="autoBonus1">Auto Click bonus (+1 donut / second) <br/> Price: $700</div>
  <div class="item" id="autoBonus2">Auto Click bonus (+2 donut / second) <br/> Price: $1000</div>
  <div class="item" id="autoBonus5">Auto Click bonus (+5 donut / click) <br/> Price: $1200</div>
  <div class="item" id="laser">Laser (+50 donut / second) <br/> Price: $2500</div>
  <li class="item" id="battery">Battery (powers laser for 2 minutes) <br/> Price: $1500</div>
  <div class="item" id="energyPotion">Energy Potion (shortens waiting time by 30 seconds) <br/> Price: $2500</div>
  <div class="item" id="key">??????</div>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you loading two versions of jquery?

Comment: One is jQuery 2.1.1 the other is jQuery UI 1.11.4

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

I just checked. They are definitely both jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code could use some refactoring, but with that said, I think I know what might be happening. You are binding a click handler to #donut. Every time #donut is clicked, the handler is called. The handler binds a click handler to #clickBonus1 every time it is called. So if the #donut click handler is called multiple times, multiple handlers are applied to #clickBonus1, which will all be called when #clickBonus1 is clicked, causing multiple alerts.

Comment: Yeah, that might be what's happening. So, should I make the items function separate from the donut click function?

Comment: But now, the function's being read before I even start clicking, and since in the beginning, you only have five dollars, the items never show up.

Comment: Will using `window.setInterval()` to check the player's money every few seconds be better?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what your code is trying to accomplish. I just know that's most likely why your callbacks are stacking. You could look into using jquery's [one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/) method rather than click(), so that the callback only fires once.